# How to query all values from a column in one table that have all values in another column in a different table?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get all the Hikers that traveled in **all** treks in Nepal.
My tables in the data base are:

Hiker: (hikerID, fullName).

HikerInTrek:(hikerID, trekName).

NepalTreks: (trekName).

I tried the following code:

```sql
SELECT fullName
FROM Hiker
WHERE hikerID = (
         SELECT hikerID 
         FROM hikerInTrek
         WHERE hikerID not in(  SELECT hikerID 
                                        FROM    ( ( SELECT hikerID, trekName         
                                                    FROM (SELECT hikerID 
                                                          FROM hikerInTrek)
                                                          cross join 
                                                          (SELECT trekName 
                                                           FROM NepalTreks)                                                      
                                                  )
                                                  EXCEPT                                         
                                                  ( SELECT hikerID, trekName                                                 
                                                    FROM hikerInTrek                                                     
                                                  ) 
                                                 )                           
                                       )
        );
```

I'm working on a website part of a homework and I've wrote this code in the PHP, but I got an error from the "if($queryResult === false) condition after the query. So I guess the query is not correct.

Comment: Please read the guidelines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, `if (queryresult==false)` does not appear in the code you've posted, you didn't say what error you get, and this query should not return `false` but a result set.

Comment: update your question  ... add   a proper data sample, your actual result  and you expected  result  ..  you questionis not clear ..

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work"?

Comment: I edited the question. Hope now it is more clear.

Comment: What rdbms are you working with?

Comment: @Ярослав Машко Why did you delete your answer? It was the only one that came close to a correct solution...

Answer (score 1):

I would use aggregation:

```
SELECT h.hikerID, h.fullName
FROM Hiker h JOIN
     HikerInTrek ht 
     ON h.hikerID = ht.hikerID JOIN
     Nepal_Treks nt 
     ON nt.TrekName = ht.TrekName
GROUP BY h.hikerID, h.fullName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT nt.TrekName) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Nepal_Treks);
```

Note that this includes `hikerID` as well.  I see no reason to assume that hikers never share the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT
     A.fullName
FROM
    Hiker A
INNER JOIN
    HikerInTrek B ON B.hikerID = A.hikerID
WHERE
    B.trekName = 'Nepal'
```

Comment: Really? This wrong, poorly formatted, code only answer got upvoted? Why?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @ZoharPeled woah! chill, i just read the link provided by marc_s

Comment: It's a bad answer because of two things: 1. It's wrong. 2. It's not really an answer, just a code dump. Even if it was correct (which it's not), it still needs an explanation. Don't get me wrong, I've posted a few code dumps myself over the years, and sometimes I still do, but usually I try to make the effort of explaining my answer, especially if I think that the OP will need that (based on the level of the question).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your `trekName` column is set up, and depending on the SQL dialect it could be something like..

```
SELECT fullName
  FROM Hiker h 
  JOIN HikerInTrek ht on h.hikerID = ht.hikerID
  JOIN Nepal_Treks nt on nt.TrekName = ht.TrekName
```

Although I'd restructure my tables to have a format like the below (using sql naming conventions)

```
Hiker
  - id
  - full_name

HikerTrek
  - id
  - hiker_id
  - trek_id

Trek
  - id
  - name
  - location_id

TrekLocation
  - id
  - name
```

Create a row in Hiker for each hiker
Create a row in TrekLocation for Nepal,
Create a row in Trek for each Trek, with location id the one for Nepal
Create a row in HikerTrek for each trek a hiker has been on,

Then you can query it like this

```
SELECT h.full_name
  FROM Hiker h
  JOIN HikerTrek ht on h.id = ht.hiker_id
  JOIN Trek t on ht.trek_id = t.id
  JOIN TrekLocation tl on t.location_id = tl.id
 WHERE tl.name = "Nepal"
```

Hope this clears things up a little.

Comment: the question sais "...Hikers that traveled in **all** treks...". The answer doesn't provide that.

Comment: Ah, the question has been edited a few times since I wrote this.